# How to automate an electric kettle?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have [this tea kettle](http://chefman.com/products/coffee-tea/rj11-17-gp/), which requires pressing two buttons one after the other ("on" and "prog") to start.

I'd like to automate that action (tying it to Tasker on my phone), and am wondering what's my simplest/cheapest option. My communication options are either WiFi or Z-Wave/ZigBee.

I'm assuming Arduino Uno Wifi is an option, but that seems like a huge overkill given how simple what I want to do is. Are there any other simpler/cheaper tools that I could use to do this?

Comment: ... ESP8266... ?

Comment: WiFi is IMHO better, since you probably already have a WiFi network. And your phone supports WiFi. Otherwise you'll need some IP-to-ZigBee gateway. The ESP8266 is very nice, there are pretty neat little "dev boards" with USB, which make programming an easy job.

Comment: You may wire the buttons and transistor (bjt or fet) parallel. This way the device will still work with the normal buttons.

Comment: If you want to connect to your phone, you'd be better of using Bluetooth.

Comment: @Gerben the kettle is too far from my bedroom for that to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use lots of options to control it from Mbed boards to the Uno with a wifi shield, to a raspberry pi to .... the list goes on.  But if it were me I would use the something like the ESP8266 which cost less than $10 usd and can be programmed with the arduino IDE (I'm assuming that is useful given the community this was posted in).  There are also lots of tutorials available online for this kind of thing.

To trigger the button you have two options: a non-destructive one and a destructive one.  For the non destructive one, use something like a solenoid in a custom mount or a servo and small lever arm to push the button.  The benefit to this is that if you change your mind you just have to move the device and you still have a perfect unharmed kettle.  Plus, you can still use it if your device breaks or malfunctions.

For the destructive option, open up the kettle to get at the buttons or button pads and solder a wire to each side.  If you're lucky you can do this so that it can still be put back together and the original button still work.  One option is to use a relay to connect them.  You can use a small solid state relay or a larger coil relay; both would be under a couple of dollars and not large enough to be too obtrusive.  Using a relay is nice since you don't have to worry about which voltages are being used on which side of the button and it isolates the microcontroller from the kettle better.  (Actually some relays are polarized so if it doesn't work, switch the wires and try again).  Another option is to use an  optoisolator like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9118) one.  It is polarized so if it doesn't work switch the wires.  Another option is to use a mosfet.  I believe it will work if you get an N channel mosfet with a Vgs (gate to source voltage) less than 3.3V.  Hook up the Source pin to the more negative of the two button leads and the Drain to the other.  Hook up the gate to a pin on the micorcontroller.  Also, you should put a resister between the gate and the source pins.

Comment: Thanks! What resistor should I add if I use this transistor: [IRLZ24N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlz24n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535671faac271c)?

Comment: It's just a pull down resistor so a wide range would work.  I'd use a 10k just because I've got a lot laying around.  Anything 1k-25k should be fine.

Comment: Here's another article that may be of use: http://little-scale.blogspot.com/2016/05/circuit-bending-basics-two-easy-was-of.html

Answer (score 2):

Replace your button with a relay and use a microcontroller to switch it.

It will be cheaper to use an ESP6266, which could be programmed with the Arduino IDE and the same Arduino code works on it. It will be perfect as it has got just 2 GPIO ports and it will just be the size of your thumb.

Comment: Calm down, you don't need a full relay to emulate a small switch, a MOSFET would be good enough.

Comment: Also, the ESP8266 has more then 2 GPIOs, I mean WAY more. You just have the ESP8266 ESP-01 breakout, the first on which has only 2 GPIOs. The ESP-12 has many more and with a custom PCB, you can have access to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

**This is simply a suggestion. It is not in your list of communication protocol that you listed but this could work great.**

A good and reliable way is to use an GSM shield with and Arduino. The GSM shield could receive a text such as "on" or "off" and could interpret those messages to control your kettle.

To emulate the switches, you can use 2 MOSFET. They act like an electronic in the sense that when you apply 5V (PNP transistor), it lets current pass and will cut the current flow when there is no voltage applied to it.

NOTE: GSM modules are quite cheap if you know where to get them. I recommended getting a chinese version because they usualy work fine for me and there price is way lower.

Comment: Hmm, I het have to find a decent+cheap GSM module. But WiFi will do in this case, since I suppose the device will always be within range of the WiFi. So you can eaily get away with a ~4$ ESP8266-12 dev board.

Comment: Pay and extra 4$ and you get something that works everywhere. https://www.amazon.com/SIM800L-Quad-band-Network-Breakout-Module/dp/B017I6QC8C/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1478086767&sr=8-7&keywords=gsm+arduino

Comment: Nice, considering I've worked with the SIM900, I should be able to figure out how to get this one working.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but I know basically nothing about GSM aside from my phone having it. Wouldn't said module need a sim card/service connection to work?

Comment: Yes it does need a SIM card

Comment: @canadiancyborg so I'd need to pay monthly fees to a cellular provider to use this? Those would greatly exceed whatever the costs of the GSM shield are, so I don't really understand this suggestion..?

Comment: Well I have a cell with unlimited data and I remove its SIM card when I need to use it in my projects.